# numpy How to get elements from a two-dimensional array, when each row of a slice has a different number of columns?

Tags: python, numpy

How to get elements from a two-dimensional array, when each row of a slice has a different number of columns?

```
buffer = np.zeros((32, 32, 3), 'u1') # this is our data buffer 2d.

buffer[2:5, (2:4, 3:7, 0:11)] # does not work.

# vertical interval: 2..5; horizontal intervals: 1..3, 4..9, 7..10 
multi_intervals = ((2, 5), ((1, 3), (4, 9), (7, 10)))

# our very slowerest function.
def gen_xy_indices(y_interval, x_multi_intervals):
    x_multi_ranges = list(map(lambda x: np.arange(*x),x_multi_intervals))
    y_range = np.arange(*y_interval)

    y_indices = np.repeat(y_range, list(map(len, x_multi_ranges)))
    x_indices = np.concatenate(x_multi_ranges)

    return x_indices, y_indices

ix, iy = gen_xy_indices(*multi_intervals)
buffer[iy, ix].shape == (10, 3) # yeah work but slow.
# IS THERE A FASTER WAY TO DO THIS?! (in python with numpy)
```

Comment: You should provide a better explanation. Each row of what? A dataframe? A single row in a list or a set?

Comment: Seconding the request for a more detailed explanation. I've had several reads through and I can't understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: As others have suggested a better explanation would be great to help you on this. How 2 got repeated 2 times and 3 4 times while 4 again 4 times?

Comment: `np.r_[2:4, 3:7, 0:11]` produces your `x_indices`.  But the underlying mechanism is the same.  Expand the slices with `arange` and concatenate.  The accepted answer uses the same idea to package your `gen_Indices` as a class.  Speed should be the same

Comment: `np.vstack([buffer[i, j[0]:j[1]] for i,j in zip(range(multi_intervals[0][0], multi_intervals[0][1]), multi_intervals[1])])` is faster in this example.  But relative results may differ in larger arrays.  Either way you have to iterate and concatenate something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.repeat` and `np.concatenate`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> class By_Row:
...     def __getitem__(self, idx):
...         y, *x = (np.arange(i.start, i.stop, i.step) for i in idx)
...         return y.repeat(np.fromiter((i.size for i in x), int, y.size)), np.concatenate(x)
... 
>>> 
>>> b_ = By_Row()
>>> 
>>> A = sum(np.ogrid[:600:100, :12])
>>> A
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11],
       [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111],
       [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211],
       [300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311],
       [400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411],
       [500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511]])
>>> A[b_[2:5, 2:4, 3:7, 0:11]]
array([202, 203, 303, 304, 305, 306, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406,
       407, 408, 409, 410])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
x = range(2,5)
y = range(17)
divs = [(2,4), (3,7), (12,17)]
y_vals = []
x_vals = []
for d, div in enumerate(divs):
    y_grp = y[div[0]:div[1]]
    y_vals += y_grp
    x_vals += [x[d]]*len(y_grp)

print(x_vals)
print(y_vals)

> [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
> [2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```